# Как обратиться к методам wcf-сервиса

Tags: c#, service, iis, wcf

Есть wcf-сервиса , который запущен на локальном IIS.(http://localhost:8080/ArmService/Service1.svc) Как обратиться к методам wcf-сервиса, передать ему параметры. На примере если можна

Comment: А конкретней можно? ServiceReference указывали или хочется без него, прописывая всё ручками?

Comment: Пожалуйста, не пишите "ИИС". Во-первых, глаза режет. Во-вторых, люди столкнувшиеся с похожей проблемой будут искать по "IIS" и не найдут ответ на ваш вопрос.

Comment: ServiceReference указывали

Comment: в теме iis не писал, автоматом докинуло

Answer (score 2):

Отлично, у Вас есть `ServiceReference`. Вероятнее всего он сгенерирован с дефолтной областью `ServiceReference1`.
Соответственно `svcutil` сгенерировал Вам класс `ServiceReference1.ServiceClient`.
Экземпляр этого класса и нужно объявить, а в нём сгенерированы методы, предоставляемые сервисом.

```
// Прокси
ServiceReference1.ServiceClient client = new ServiceReference1.ServiceClient();
// Вызов метода
client.MyMethod();
// Закрываем прокси
if (client.State != CommunicationState.Faulted)
    client.Close();
else
    client.Abort();
```

Comment: А если без указания ServiceReference?

Comment: Много букв и довольно неплохое понимание того, что из себя представляют привязки (binding), изучение wsdl, которую предоставляет сервис, так как возвращаемые/принимаемы типы всё же объявить придётся и т.д. и т.п.

Написать могу, конечно, но чаще возникают конкретные вопросы, например, про поддержку сессий той или иной привязкой, нежели желание кого-то с нуля писать работу с сервисами.